# Winform create table in RichTextBox control

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I need to create a simple editor using a RichTextBox control in a windows forms application that includes the ability to create tables.

Is it possible to create a table in a RichTextBox control?

If so, any pointers on the best way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: This link explains how to insert table in rich text box.[Insert Table In Rich TextBox control](http://www.techymedia.com/post/2012/08/12/Table-in-Richtextbox-Using-C.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winforms RichTextbox control utilizes RTF as it's rich-format language. As such tables are an inherent part of the control, you just must know enough RTF to code up the table.

Here's the [1.9.1 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DD422B8D-FF06-4207-B476-6B5396A18A2B&displaylang=en).  Enjoy.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#External_links) has all the specifications listed on it

Comment: First link is dead, here's one where specifications may be found: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000473.shtml